# MySQL do where on more than one field

Tags: mysql

I want to do a WHERE on more than one field. And it also has to be in between two numbers. I think you can understand it more by looking at the code:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE(lat BETWEEN 8 AND 100) AND WHERE(lng BETWEEN 1 AND 4)
```

Thanks for any responses

Comment: This has already been answered, but FYI, `WHERE` is a clause as opposed to a function (which it looks like you have interpreted it as). You only need to use brackets when you're including both `AND` and `OR` in your `WHERE` statements. If you're only using either `AND` or `OR` and not both then you don't need brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there, just that you don't need to use `WHERE` twice, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM locations 
WHERE lat BETWEEN 8 AND 100 
AND lng BETWEEN 1 AND 4;
```